# Difference between getSession() and getNewSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm, transactions

Using Spring's SessionFactoryUtils for Hibernate, what is the actual difference between getSession() and getNewSession()?

I've been getSession() in a DAO method, but when it started to get called quite often, a bunch of "Session is closed" exceptions started to appear. I changed it to getNewSession(...), and now as if these problems have gone away ... but still, I need to know.

Please, explain.

Comment: Doesn't it open a new connection each time you invoke it?

Answer (score 4):

`getSession()` will try to find a pre-existing Session that's bound to the current thread, creating one if necessary.  `getNewSession()` will always create the session.  Javadocs here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/SessionFactoryUtils.html.

If you feel like you're getting the session is closed error too often, try to find where your session is being released.

Comment: Ok, got it - getSession(...) is a somewhat more optimized variant of getNewSession(...). Now the session.closed exceptions are gone, but I have java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket. Any clue?

Comment: @xantrus - ask that as a different question, and provide the stacktrace.